# how to handle logging for model changes?

Tags: oop, logging, model

We have a web site where people can make changes to the relationships between models (posts and topics). Users can add topics to posts. admins can change it, and other systems (eg crons) can change it, etc.  We would like to log this so we can know what the changes were and whom made them.

The question is where this logging belongs.  We don't want to put it in controllers because any other flow (like crons) or where its incidental and it might be forgotten.

But putting the logging logic into the Model seems strange - but I not sure how else to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Create a designated log controller (with accompanying model), and call it from all other controllers that need logging.
That way you don't put the logic in the model, and it's centrally available for use with other controllers or API's that might need to use it.

Comment: thanks - I'm not sure I follow the idea of the "log controller".  Lets say my request comes into the REST_Post controller with an update_topics method.  Inside that method, I get the topics from the input and update the topics for the post.  Where does the log controller interface?

Answer (score 2):

In popular ORMs like Hibernate (Java), Doctrine (PHP) you can register listeners for entity lifecycle events. You can use such pattern to register your logger.

Here's some explanation about Doctrine life cycle events
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#implementing-event-listeners

Basically framework provides you a way to attach event listener by using annotation to any entity you want to persist using the ORM.
You can create f.e. generic EntityChangesLoggingListener and attach it to all your entities as listener.
The listener will be feed with details about changed fields of an entity before or after it is saved in database - all informations are provided in event object.
And you can simply put those details to any kind of log you like.

Advantages:

- your logger is loosely coupled with the model - only by annotation.
- your logger is very close to data store save action, so there is little risk that you will skip logging of changes during implementation of some new features modifying given entity state.
- if you want to store log records in the same database as entities it's easy to do both in a single database transaction if you like

If you decide to log in controller layer as @Avi Kehat suggested i see few disadvantages

- controller is very first layer where you proccess data so there is a big risk that something will fail in the middle - between user action and logging action.
  and as a result you will have no logs.
- if you call log controller from every other controller, then logging will be tied coupled with domain actions

If you don't use any ORM which supports handling of entities lifecycle events, then I would go with some EventDispatcher. Then you can decide when you want to raise an event about some important data change (in controller layer or model) and registered listener will get this event and write log. In the future maybe you will find it usefull to attach another listener to do something more f.e. refreshing some statistics etc.

Comment: Thanks!  do you think this is the better approach to how to handle it or it's fine to put the logging logic in the model?

Comment: Putting logging logic to model is bad. But if you want log model changes then logger should be as close to model as possible but loosely coupled (!) by using Observer pattern or Events